# Tem alguma forma de fazer a SpeechRecognition{python} esperar até o usuário falar?

Tags: python-3.x, biblioteca, reconhecimento-de-voz

Estou fazendo um programa que vai me retornar uma resposta de acordo com oque eu falar pra ele, para isso usei a biblioteca SpeechRecognition para pegar o que eu falar e passar como parâmetro, só que eu percebi que se eu não falar nada é emitido um erro e o programa encerra, isso por que eu acabei não falando nada, então eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer ele esperar eu falar?
O código:

```
def escutar_microfone():
    microfone = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        microfone.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Fale, estou escutando!!")
        audio = microfone.listen(source)
        try:
            frase = microfone.recognize_google(audio, language='pt-BR')
            return frase.lower()
        except:
            print("Erro")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
while True :
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Diga algo!")
        audio = r.listen(source,timeout = None)
    try:
        print("Você disse: " + r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'pt-BR'))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        pass
```

Acho que colocando em loop resolve seu problema.